# How do you update a mongodb document while replacing the entire document?

Tags: php, mongodb

If I have a document with two values:

```
{
  "name" : "Bob",
  "location" "France"
}
```

And then pass an array to the document that contains "name", "country". How do I ensure that the entire document is updated, with "location" removed?

I will not be aware of the differences between the two documents, so I wont be able to unset a specific field. I am looking for a method to simply replace the document data with the array supplied.

Comment: It's not possible to have a document in MongoDB that only has those two values - it must also have an _id field which will uniquely identify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you supply `update` with a new document containing the records you want, you will replace the document.

For example:

```
db.so.insert({"name":"Bob", "location": "France"})
db.so.update({"name":"Bob", "location": "France"}, {"name":"Roberto", "country":"Italy"})
db.so.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId(), "name" : "Roberto", "country" : "Italy" }
```

Of course, if you had the `_id` of the document, this would be a better way of specifying the update (rather than passing back the document you just inserted like above)

Comment: So, to do a full update I would need to pass the original document array along with the new document array? I've been just passing the new array and only now realized it wasnt removing fields that were not in the new array.

Comment: You only need to identify to document.  In the example above I am doing that by passing the original document back, which uniquely identifies the document.  You could do the same by passing an `_id` of an existing document you want to update.  Check out the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.updates.php) on updating in PHP, which shows the difference between updates that replace and updates that just modify part of a document.